# Missing a “Permissions” manifest attribute in Java

Tags: java

I have some problems with opening a SAN switch in Webtools (Java version 8 Update 31).

The first problem was a failed to validate certificate

[image: failed to validate certificate]

This was fixed by following the instructions on [this site](http://michlstechblog.info/blog/java-error-failed-to-validate-certificate-the-application-will-not-be-executed/)

However, then I got following error:
[image: blocked an application]

Which was solved by adding these 3 entries to the site to the exception site list (the last one is the only one necessary I think)

```
http://i.p.address/*
http://i.p.address/switchExplorer.html
http://i.p.address/
```

But now I get following error:

```
your security settings have blocked an application from running due to missing a “permissions” manifest attribute in the main jar web tools
```

[image: missing manifest attribute]

The solution seems to be adding the URL to the exceptions but I have already done that in the previous step..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the "Mission Control Panel" of java.

If you cannot find it, have a look in the `bin` folder of your jdk installation, the executable should be called `jcontrol`.

Run it, open tab "Security", Button "Edit Site List" and add your URL to the Exception Site List. I.e. `https://10.0.0.1` is all you need.

Use oracle java if you use linux and somehow miss `jcontrol` from the openjdk package.

Afterwards you should be able to start the .jnlp (or however you want to start the applet) of your desire.